# How do I refer to the beginning and end of a parametric curve?

Tags: curves

I have a parametric curve $\vec r(t)$ with domain $t \in [0, L]$, where L is the arc length of the curve. Is there any technical term to refer to the begin (the point of $\vec r(0)$ and end (the point of $\vec r(L)$) of the parametric curve?

Context: I'm working on a game where racetracks are parametric curves and racetracks are joined together through either end (begin/end) of each curve. I found the names `enum TrackBeginOrEnd { Begin, End }` very awkward.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. $r(0)$ is the point you want (I  omitted the arrow because I was too lazy to add it).

Comment: "Beginning point or start point", and "finish point or end point" seem to be pretty clear and self explaining terms.

Comment: Head and tail maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beginning and end of a [path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28topology%29) are called the "endpoints."  I have tended to call them the "start" or "beginning" and the "end" of the path myself, when I need to distinguish between them.  Here, a path is a function $[0,1]\to X$ for some space $X$.